# iOS 10 iPhone custom sound as Ringtone

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ringtone

I want to set a custom ringtone from my iOS app. 
Is adding a ringtone possible in the UIActivityController?
I've seen examples of it before, but I haven't been able to do it myself.

Reference images: [img1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/br63iwqj0opce3q/Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%207.18.28%20PM.png?dl=0)[img2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ex1t2twhfkkse64/Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%207.21.30%20PM.png?dl=0)[img3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1dfoyf1gv10sjej/Screen%20Shot%202018-01-06%20at%207.21.46%20PM.png?dl=0)

Please help me if you have better solutions.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apps are not able to set the ringtone directly.  By the looks of those examples they are not setting the actual ringtone of the phone.